# Difference in proportion: Pre-post intervention-control study design

Tags: proportion, meta-analysis, group-differences

I am conducting a meta-analysis where I want to compare the proportion of samples pre- vs post- intervention. To do this, I have been calculating the difference in proportion (Post - Pre) as the effect size estimator. However, I have some studies were I have pre-post data in control and intervention groups. What's the best way to perform the data analysis for such studies?

One thing that I thought about doing is to calculate the difference in proportion separately for intervention and control groups. But is this appropriate?

Thanks in advance!